# Check if key is present in list of dictionaries and if true return dictionary index in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I'm trying to check if there is a key in each dictionary called 'tag' with a value of 'staging automator'. If this is true then create a new list with just those dictionaries.

```
    myList = [
    {
        "@location": "vsys",
        "@name": "reactor-test",
        "@vsys": "vsys1",
        "dynamic": {
            "filter": "'reactor' or 'ACI-Reactor_epg'"
        },
        "tag": {
            "member": [
                "reactor"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "@location": "vsys",
        "@name": "Customer Access",
        "@vsys": "vsys1",
        "description": "Allowed addresses for external customers",
        "static": {
            "member": [
                "GG-sub"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "@location": "vsys",
        "@name": "test-dynamic-group",
        "@vsys": "vsys1",
        "dynamic": {
            "filter": "'staging-automator'"
        }
    },
    {
        "@location": "vsys",
        "@name": "MyDynamicGroup",
        "@vsys": "vsys1",
        "description": "I edited this via postman because I'm cool.",
        "dynamic": {
            "filter": "staging-automator"
        },
        "tag": {
            "member": [
                "staging-automator"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So far I've come up with this which will tell me which dictionaries in the list contain what I'm looking for:

```
for item in myList:
    if "tag" in item.keys():
        if item["tag"]["member"][0] == "staging-automator":
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
    else:
        print("False")
```

But I'm stuck with how to then grab that dictionary out of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```
new_list = []
for item in your_dictionaries:
    if "tag" in item.keys():
        if item["tag"]["member"][0] == "staging-automator":
            new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Doh! How obvious. I think I just had mental block. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better for future readers if you provide an exaplation.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the loop you already have your desired dictionary!

Where you are checking for the `staging-automator`, the `item` variable is your required thing; just append it to a new list.

Here's how it can be done

```py
new_list = []
        
for item in myList:
    if "tag" in item:
        if item["tag"]["member"][0] == "staging-automator":
            print("True")
            new_list.append(item)
            continue
    print("False")

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Why used `continue`, and you can add an `else` statement to print False, as now even if 'tag' is present in dict it would show False.

Comment: No it won't show False if `tag` is present in the dict, and that's what `continue` is for. Also it was just to avoid the repetition that the original code by OP had.
You can run it to confirm.

Comment: i have understood it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
# Method 1
# a is the list of dict you have provided 
tag_list=[]
for i in a:
      if "tag" in i:
            if i["tag"]['member'][0]=="staging-automator":
                  tag_list.append(i)

# Method 2
a=[]
for i in myList:
    j=str(i)
    j=j.replace(" ","")
    if "'tag':{'member':['staging-automator']}" in j:
        a.append(i)
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
# For Method 1
b=[i for i in a if "tag" in i if i["tag"]['member'][0]=="staging-automator"]
print(b)

# For Method 2
a=[i for i in myList if "'tag':{'member':['staging-automator']}" in str(i).replace(" ","")]
```

Explanation Method 1:

- Just readed the items in the list,
- checked if "tag" is present in the item,
- if preset then again checked if `tags:member`'s attributes is "staging-automator",
- if that too is true then, i have appended it to the `tag_list`.

Explanation Method 2:

- Converted the dict into string so that we can easily search for specific item in the string.
- used `.replace()` in order to removes spaces.
- Check if `"'tag':{'member':['staging-automator']}"` is present in the string, if present then appended the dict to new list.

`in` searches if the given value is present in any data type for example in string, list, tuple ect.

**List comprehension would be useful if you are having a large dict, as its faster than the normal `for-loop`.**

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter instead of a loop. There are certainly cases where appending to a list from inside a loop is a good option, but this is not one of them. The list comprehension suggested by @Faraaz Kurawle is also ok.

```
def check_item(item):
    return "tag" in item and item["tag"]["member"][0] == "staging-automator"

list(filter(check_item, myList))
```